# How to add a record to a MySQL Database from JDBC

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, addition, records

Im having an issue trying to add a record to a MySQL Database.
My database has 5 columns (id,names,players,points,position) and i have declared the id as "Auto-Increment " and "primary". Then, when i am trying to add a record, i get the error ***Column count doesn't match value count at row 1***. This happens when my code has this statement,not asking input form a user becuase the id is supposed to auto-increment itself from the database.

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO teams VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
```

I was told that I shouldn't add another ? to the VALUES() because i dont need to auto-increment it again.

This is my code :

```
try
  {    
   conn_pr1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
   conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
   stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();
   rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM teams");
   String sql1 = "INSERT INTO teams VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
   ps1 =conn_pr1.prepareStatement(sql1);
   String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Team name : ");
   String str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Players : ");
   String str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Points : ");
   String str4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Position : ");
   int int2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
   int int3 = Integer.parseInt(str3);
   int int4 = Integer.parseInt(str4);
   ps1.setString(1,str1);
   ps1.setLong(2,int2);
   ps1.setLong(3,int3);
   ps1.setLong(4,int4);
   ps1.executeUpdate();
   System.out.println("\n Successfully added " + str1 + " to database test1!");
                            System.out.println("\n After Changes : ");

                                              System.out.println("___________________________________________________________________________________");
  while (rs1.next())
      {
        System.out.println(" Id : " + rs1.getString(1) + " | Team : " + rs1.getString(2) + " | Players : " + rs1.getString(3) + " | Points : " + rs1.getString(4) + " | Position : " + rs1.getString(5));
      }
        conn1.close();
        conn_pr1.close();
        stmt1.close();
        ps1.close();
        rs1.close();
   } catch ( SQLException se)
        {
        se.printStackTrace();
        }
}
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT INTO teams (names,players,points,position) VALUES (?,?,?,?)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly specify the columns you want to insert, currently you have less parameter placeholders than the table has columns. You need to make explicit that you don't want to insert the ID column so that it is handled by the auto-increment. Use:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)
```